# Javascript "next" button with checkbox "show hide Div"

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a site with several Questions and i want an survey to click throw a few "divs" and with a check box if they want to give no answer:

!!! Every thing works but if i type in 0 in the input field the alert comes but then i Can't get further ? WHY !!!

My code for the Checkbox:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBoxFeld" name="CheckBox2" >
```

My Code For the Next Button:

```
 <a href="#" class="Button" onclick="onclick=check2();"><input type="button" value="Next"></a>
```

My Code for the TEST:

```
 function check2(){

    var field = document.Survey.Answer2.value;
    var checkbox2 = document.Survey.CheckBox2.checked;


    if (field == 0 && checkbox2 == false){


        alert("Please answer question 2");


    }
    else{

        showHideDiv('Question2', 'Question3');

    }


}
```

And my Code for the ShowHide Function:

```
 // Show and Hide Div
   function showHideDiv(idHide, idShow){

    //document.getElementById(idShow).style.display = "block";
    //document.getElementById(idHide).style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById(idHide).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById(idShow).style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

Comment: `onclick="onclick=check2();` should just be `onclick="check2()"`

Comment: `onclick="onclick=check2();` shoule be `onclick="check2();`

Comment: `onclick="onclick=check2();"` should be `onclick="return check2();"` and you should return false at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the length of the value:

```
function check2(){

    var field = document.Survey.Answer2.value;
    var checkbox2 = document.Survey.CheckBox2.checked;


    if (field.length == 0 && checkbox2 == false){


        alert("Please answer question 2");


    }
    else{

        showHideDiv('Question2', 'Question3');

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using, `onclick="check2();"` instead of `onclick="onclick=check2();"`

```
  <input type="button" class="Button" value="Next"  onclick="check2();">
```

Javascript:

```
function check2(){
    var field = document.Survey.Answer2.value;
    var checkbox2 = document.Survey.CheckBox2.checked;

    if (field == 0 && checkbox2 == false){
    alert("Please answer question 2");

    }
    else{
    showHideDiv('Question2', 'Question3');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The return false would not help, since the function is bound to an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues

1. poor practice and illegal html to wrap a button in a link
2. if you use a link, return false to avoid the HREF to be followed. In this case the browser would likely go to top and some browsers would partially unload the page, making for example animations stop

Like this

```
<a href="#" class="Button" onclick="return check2();">Next</a>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" onclick="check2()" value="Next">
```

using

```
function check2(){
  var field = document.Survey.Answer2.value;
  var checkbox2 = document.Survey.CheckBox2.checked;
  if (field == 0 && !checkbox2){
    alert("Please answer question 2");
  }
  else{
    showHideDiv('Question2', 'Question3');
  }
  return false;
}
```

But only if your field contains 0. 
If you want to test if it is empty, you need field.length==0 instead